# Task based programming with same efficiency as multiple instances of the application

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, rabbitmq, threadpool

I have created a windows service that consumes messages from a RabbitMq.
The consumption is done in a async manner, where messages are pushed to the service.

It scales well horizontally with an approx. linear performance gain, even when just creating more service instances on the same server.
Since we have a defined goal on throughput, i find it a bit more simple, deployment wise to control scaling by simply creating n number of tasks within the windows service, rather than deploying n number of service instances.

Rewriting the windows service to simply start n tasks that each run the "MQ consumption" code, thus in essence doing what multiple instance of the windows service does, does not yield the same performance, effectively there is not performance gain at all, it actually seems that there is a larger overhead on code execution!.

I do know that there are scheduling issues, but the bottom line question is.
**would it be possible to use tasks and get the "approximately" same performance as if one started multiple instances of the application?** and if so, how would an implementation look like, because my current setup scales poorly.

Some code snippets:

This is the basic task creation, where each task has an instance of the taskwrapper, that basically is an abstraction of the whole business logic of consuming and processing messages:

```
public void Start()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < _levelOfConcurrency; i++)
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new TaskWrapper().TaskRun(_cancelationTokenSource.Token,_sleeptime),
                TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            _tasks[i] = task;
            Console.WriteLine("Task created {0}", i);
        }
    }

 public void Stop()
    {
        _cancelationTokenSource.Cancel();
        Task.WaitAll(_tasks);
    }
```

This is what each task basically has in they runloop in the taskwrapper class:

```
public void TaskRun(CancellationToken cancellationToken,TimeSpan sleeptime)
    {
        _semaphoreDataController.Start(); // Process messages async, fully selfcontained/threaded

        //Keep alive and occasionally check if cancelation is requested
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(sleeptime);
        }
        Dispose();
    }
```

I hope someone can enlighten me :-D

Comment: Is `Thread.Sleep(sleeptime)` a placeholder for some logic? Or is it literally there?

Comment: There is no need for the task to check if it has been cancelled too fast, thus the sleep. the underlying processes in the semaphoreDataController are threaded and runs even thou the task is in a sleep state.

Answer (score 0):

To the core of your question:

It hardly depends on your programming style and the program it self.

It is possible to gain the same performance with one multi-threaded process as with multiple instances. But as I said this depends on your service. I would recommend you to read this online version of the book: [Parallel programming with .net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx). It opened my eyes about PLinq, task and threads.

But in the end, its all running on your CPU and interprocess communication is more complex than the inter-thread one.

Answer (score 0):

So further investigation has determined the primary limiting factor in the code.

The way i use communicate with RabbitMQ is via Burrow.NET, and it will create a dedicated channel for the application to communicate with the queue.

This means that even thou n number of parallel tasks are running they can only consume from the queue from one channel, thus limiting the speed of the service.

Having multiple instances of the service, provides n number of channels to the RabbitMQ, thus linear performance gain.

Comment: As an intermediate solution, which I use for this very use case, you can have one controller process launch N processes (not tasks). The big advantage is fault-recovery : if one goes down, it's easy to relaunch. Also, it's easy to allow it to receive control messages to add/remove processes.

Comment: RabbitMQ will deliver messages to a channel as fast as the network connection will allow up to the pre-fetch count. As each message is ACK'd another message is delivered. I don't know how Burrow implements this, but if you can increase the pre-fetch count that might improve things. Alternatively, channels and consumers are cheap and you can multiplex many over the same connection, so why not simply create a consumer per thread?

Answer (score 0):

The DedicatedPublishingChannel as its name is used for publishing messages only so I don't think It made the speed problem of consuming messages.
Beside, eventhough there is only 1 channel to subscribe from the queue, the speed of messages being delivered to the application is always very fast compare to the time to process those messages. I've made an application to migrate millions of msgs (Tweet json) from the queue to MongoDB and it's always a bottle neck of writting data to database.

Burrow.NET handles the task management to process messages in parallel for you:

```
ITunnel tunnel;
// Create tunnel
tunnel.Subscribe(new SubscriptionOption<Message>
{
    BatchSize = 10, // Number of threads you want to process those messages
    MessageHandler = message => 
    {
        // Process your message here
    },
    QueuePrefetchSize = 10, // Should be double the message processing speed
    SubscriptionName = "Anything"
});
// Message will be acked automatically after finish
```

In my opinion, I would just use as limit IO resource as possible. I got a problem that my application created so many channels and ate quote alot server's memory, It's even worse if the app creates many unneccessary connections, that's why Burrow.NET will help you make as less connections/channels as possible.

If you think that your messages can be processed fast enough, you can set the prefetch size with a high number and tune it with the BatchSize (aka thread count). For example, if my app could process messages from a queue at 5msgs/sec, I would keep the QueuePrefetchSize = 10.

If you use the above method with auto ack, you won't have to worry about not ack the messaage because it will block the new messages to come. For instance, you have QueuePrefetchSize = 10 to have 10 messages being processed in parallel by 10 threads. You decided to use tunnel.SubscribeAsync with asynchronously ack the message but for some reasons (an unhandled exception :D may be) 4 of messages were not acked, it would be equivalent to having a QueuePrefetchSize of 6. Therefore, only 6 messages can be processed the same time and properly the speed will decrease. So please try the approach above and see how it goes.